# What's the possible reason of non-custom signed APK (generated via debugging) running fine but the custom signed APK (release) not working?

Tags: android, xamarin, deployment, xamarin.android, publish

My Android app is coming to the end. Debugging runs OK for many many times without any error. It runs just fine. It's the time for me to build a release and publish the app. I follow all the steps which can be found via Google easily. In fact the signed APK is installed OK and the app starts OK *but* if user interacts to navigate between screens of the app, it is crashed for no reason. Not all screen switching causes app crash, just some of them and I can notice that maybe it involves `Reflection` here. I design my own binding system to bind ViewModel behind with the `Fragment` and using `Reflection` is a must, no other way.

I totally believe that it is not any fault in my code because ***the app runs just fine*** in debug mode. And at the time of nearly completely losing all hope to publish the app, I found a signed version of the APK file in the ***debug*** folder (that signed version is generated only if you start debugging the app to run in some targeted device - even some emulator, building in Debug mode won't generate that file). It's very lucky for me that that signed apk ***works*** perfectly. I can deploy that APK to a new device and install normally, the app runs expectedly.

So it must be something wrong with the releasing process. Here is some info about configuration for Release mode (mainly in *Android Options* tab):

- Packaging (Packaging properties): Nothing is checked in here.
- Linker: I tried both ***Sdk assemblies only*** and ***Sdk and user assemblies*** but nothing works.
- Advanced properties: I checked all options to support all possible CPU architectures (this should not be a problem because in debug mode, all these options are also checked).

At the beginning of learning Xamarin Android, I tried finding information about publishing Android app and did complete a simple test (to deploy a simple app). It worked OK at that time (maybe because it's too simple), but now when it comes to a complex one (mainly involving my binding system which uses reflection heavily) it can be crashed at some user interactions. I also have a separate library project (containing some custom Views) referenced OK in my main project (not sure if that could be a break, however one custom view is used OK while some others may cause crashing). Because all the crashes happen in a compiled build, I cannot debug anything to see what could be wrong.

No code is provided here because there is too much code, it seems to be crashed at many places and one more important reason is the code should not be the problem (for one reason I explained above - it just runs smoothly in debug mode, I even found a signed APK file in debug folder which can be installed OK and the app then runs just OK like in debug mode).

Comment: I don't know what configurations are in Xamarin, but do you have Proguard enabled (minifyEnabled=true in build.gradle) ?

Comment: As per the my experience it could be the progaurd problem. If we do not keep or ignore proper classes name inside progaurd file then it becomes problem after signed apk. if progaurd enabled.

Comment: @Laura I think the build.gradle is not present (or somehow hidden) in Xamarin Android project, but it does have an option called `Proguard` in the project properties, and that option is not enabled. Thank you.

Comment: @AjitDubey thank you for your feedback, could you give me some suggestion to check or solve the problem (if it could be related to proguard)? There are some things unclear to me here: you mentioned about `proguard file` but I'm not sure where it is in my Xamarin Android project, thanks again.

Comment: @Hopeless In my case progaurd file was there. Signed apk when I was launch that application every time going to crash but in debug mode it was working fine. Then I logged each and every line where I was parsing data and binding into model. I found null value into model because of I had not kept that model class inside progaurd. Once I kept that model class inside progaurd file then it was working fine.

Comment: @Hopeless 1) In the `Android Build` Settings, disable `Proguard` if selected and under `Linker Options` change it to **`Don't Link`** and rebuild a release build, Archive another `.apk` and install/retest. This will at least determine if the C# Linker is the issue about removed methods. (I doubt this is the issue, but try it) 2) Setup `HockeyApp` in your app to capture and symbolize your release mode crashes and stack traces... I would *assume* doing this you will be able to quickly determine if it null related and a GC issue or a OOM/object allocation issue, etc......

Comment: @SushiHangover well I remember I tried that option too (but not really sure if some other was also checked). Now I've just tried what you suggested (the first suggestion) and it worked! It is surely a problem of the linker. Thank you very much. Do you have anything to do if that's a problem of the linker? Or we can simply don't use the linker (is there any problem with that except the APK file size becomes much larger - for my app with linker the size is about 19MB, without linker, it goes up to 52MB). Finally you could post an answer if you want, thanks again

Comment: @AjitDubey thank you, as I understand it means you use `proguard`? In my case I don't use that option, so the issue may be a bit different.

Comment: @Hopeless it could be brother.....

Comment: @AjitDubey do you use linker option with proguard enabled? I'll try enabling proguard and see if it works and in case there is some issue (similar to yours), I'll try looking in the proguard file and see if it can be solved like what you said. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you stated you are using a **lot of reflection**, the first thing to do is:

- In the Android Build Settings:

  - Disable Proguard if it selected
  - Change the Linker Options to **`Don't Link`**
  - Rebuild a release build

**Update**: Since this worked and the app no longer crashes.

> The linker will sometimes remove code that you want to preserve. 
>   For example:

You will need to determine what classes and/or method are being remove because that have no direct references and are only called via reflection and preserve those to prevent the linker from removing them.

If they are in your code, you can use the [Preserve] attribute.

If they are 3rd party libs or the `Xamarin.Android` framework, you can create a "hardcoded" *fake* reference to those classes/members so the linker *sees* that you need them.

> - You might have code that you call dynamically via System.Reflection.MemberInfo.Invoke.
> - If you instantiate types dynamically, you may want to preserve the default constructor of your types.
> - If you use XML serialization, you may want to preserve the properties of your types.

Ref: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/

Comment: thank you, this answer is really helpful. Before I make the linker work for my project, I would just not use it for initial deployment.

Comment: I've tried changing the configuration in Debug mode to make it like in Release mode (`Use Shared Runtime` is unchecked and the linker is `Sdk assemblies only`). Now at least when debugging the project, it behaves fairly like what it does in the release build. So I can debug it and detect 1 strange thing involving reflection here. One `View` on my Fragment is a `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText` (that's what shown at debugging time, although in the layout file I just use the `<EditText>` element ... (to be continued, see the below comment)

Comment: ...The reflection obtains the property `Text` of that View and via debugging I can see that `CanRead` property is ***false*** while `CanWrite` is true. Yes that's very very strange to me. That's one reason making the getter just return `null` (while it should invoke the getter to obtain the value of `Text` property which is entered by user). So do you have any idea on why that could happen? I'm step by step digging into each strange issue which is present only in release build. Thanks.